# Syncing Ubuntu One from LAN

Tags: ubuntu-one

Does Ubuntu One look for sources of files it needs to download on the LAN before it goes off and grabs them from the cloud? I live in Australia, and we have download limits here, so I'm nervous that having Ubuntu One installed on a few computers could burn my available downloads pretty fast.

I know it is possible to get around this with rsync, but if I'm doing that, I don't really need Ubuntu One, and it is likely that Ubuntu One will realise there have been changes much faster than my cron jobs will.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently not at the moment. There's [a bug report requesting this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/375302).

Here are the notes from the UDS-O session:

- http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-o/meeting/desktop-o-ubuntuone-lan-sync/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Dropbox allows this:
https://www.dropbox.com/help/137/en