# Does Ubuntu One offer Windows Live Sync type services?

Tags: ubuntu-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syncing Ubuntu One from LAN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7061/syncing-ubuntu-one-from-lan)

I'm an Ubuntu convert from Windows and I'm liking it very much. One of the few things I miss in Windows is their Live Sync. I don't know what it's like now or whether it still exists, but at the time (2008/2009), Windows Live Sync lets you sync folders between computers without uploading contents on their server. That is, only the metadata of the subscribed folders are uploaded (things like changelog etc.). I really liked that, and I was wondering if Ubuntu One has an option that does the same thing? At the moment it only seems to have the option to upload all file contents on the web, and I'd rather not do that.

If Ubuntu One doesn't have the service similar to Windows Live Sync as described above, then I really recommend it. I would greatly appreciate it if someone can point me to the right place to make my recommendations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: agreed, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe we do not have this feature. The best way to recommend such a thing would be to file a bug in https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client and mark is as a wishlist.